# How can I recieive confirmation for delivered email with JavaMail API?

Tags: java, email, smtp, email-confirmation

I'm writing a program, that sends email messages and want to know when the receiver receives the email message I've sent to him. How can I do this using JavaMail API?

If I use SMTPMessage, how exactly to deal with the result after I've set the notify options?

```
SMTPMessage smtpMsg = new SMTPMessage(msg);
smtpMsg.setNotifyOptions(SMTPMessage.NOTIFY_SUCCESS);
```

Answer (score 23):

There is no standard way of doing this that's accepted and honored across the board.  I see that you have some options, though:

- Add a header "Return-Receipt-To" with your e-mail address in the value.  If the recipient of the e-mail has a client which honors this header, then a return receipt will be sent to you when the e-mail is opened.  This is not reliable, mind you, as the user can always decide not to send the receipt, even if he has a client that supports it.
- Add an image into your e-mail that loads from your server and put a parameter on the image that includes the user's e-mail address.  When the e-mail loads, the image will load from your server.  Write a script that collects the e-mail parameter and then delivers a blank image.  This is also not reliable, however, as many mail clients prompt users if they wish to download images and they can always choose not to.  Also, some (mostly older) e-mail clients do not support images.
- Perhaps the most reliable way is not to include the message in your e-mail at all.  Include only a link to a website where the message can be read, and include their e-mail address or a unique code in the link.  This way, you know exactly who read the message.  Of course, this has the downside that people aren't actually getting the message in their inbox, and they also may choose not to go to the website to read it.

Ultimately, I think you're going to have to come up with a creative solution to solve this problem, unless you're happy getting spotty results.

Comment: A notification on SMTPMessage is going to notify you of successful delivery to the recipient's mailbox server, not to their desktop, or that they read it.

Comment: oh, I made a mistake, sorry. I meant I need a notification when the message is delivered.

Comment: Then I think you have found your solution.  This should happen almost immediately.

Comment: For MS Office Outlook 2007, if you want it to prompt the recipient for a read receipt, use the "Disposition-Notification-To" header.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this is an old discussion, but:

## I've found a simple and working solution [here](http://deckerix.com/blog/mandar-confirmacion-de-lectura-con-java-api-mail/) (link in spanish).

You just need to add one more field to the header of the message. To achieve this you must use method `addHeader` of `Part` class, implemented by `Message` class. **This method receives 2 parameters, `type` and `value` of header.**

To get confirmation you must add this header:

```
Disposition-Notification-To
```

And the `value` is the mail where we want to send the confirmation answer:

```
message.addHeader("Disposition-Notification-To","mail@example.com");
```

**ATTENTION:** be aware that, nowadays, a lot of mail servers like gmail are discarding this requests, so this will not have effect, but, if you are sure (like me) receiver server allows this, will work like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

please see my answer here (when this questioned was asked about ruby on rails).  Tis basically the same answer.

[Email open notification - ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525145/email-open-notification-ruby-on-rails/3525199#3525199)

Answer (score 1):

There is another approach to finding out whether an email has been received or not, it's getting undelivered emails. I've seen  a rather good Java implementation [here](http://cases.azoft.com/implementing-notifications-using-javamail/).

They used javax.mail (for mail processing) and guava (for processing strings and collections).

Answer (score 1):

Just add a dummy image with display set to none in your message.And set the src attribute of this image to the url you want to call

Answer (score 0):

You can use SMTP message and request for a delivery status (I don't know if it's coming when the provider receive the mail or if it's when the user open the mail). 
JavaMail don't support directly these feature directly and you have to read the RFC 3464.
I also find this thread with examples but didn't try it [javamail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502941/javamail-delivery-status-problem)

You can also look at [websina](http://www.websina.com/bugzero/kb/sunmail-properties.html)