# Javamail (SMTPMessage/MimeMessage): ask for confirmation if the email was seen

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I'm currently working on a simple app in Java that sends emails and I was wondering how can I make a message (MimeMessage/SMTPMessage) that asks to send confirmation (which says that the message was seen by recipient) after opening the message. I have received some messages like this in the past.

Thanks for your help,
Assaultus Maximus :)

Comment: you can send custom html message

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676919/how-can-i-recieive-confirmation-for-delivered-email-with-javamail-api

Answer (score -1):

```
SMTPMessage msg = new SMTPMessage(session);
// msg.addHeader("Disposition-Notification-To","info@host");
msg.setReturnOption(SMTPMessage.RETURN_FULL);
msg.setNotifyOptions(SMTPMessage.NOTIFY_SUCCESS);
```